# Smooth morphism induced by the action of group schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, algebraic-groups, group-schemes

Let $R$ be a discrete valuation ring of characteristic $0$ and furthermore let $G$  be a connected, simply connected,split semisimple, affine algebraic group scheme over $R$. Furthermore, let $X$ be a $R$-scheme equipped with a $G$ action $\phi:G \times X \mapsto X$.

What conditions one would like to be imposed on the morphism $\phi$ so that it becomes smooth? I know that in the case of group schemes over a field the condition is that $G$ is smooth.
Thank you

Comment: The same argument as in the case $R$ is a field shows that $G$ being smooth is sufficient for $\phi$ to be smooth. There's an isomorphism between the action $\phi:G\times X\rightarrow X$ and the projection $\pi:G\times X\rightarrow X$. Since base change of a smooth map is smooth, if $G\rightarrow R$ is smooth, then so is $\pi$ and hence so is $\phi$.

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you please explain why there is an isomorphism between $\phi$ and $\pi$?

Comment: They fit in a commutative diagram with maps $X\rightarrow X$ the identity, and $G\times X\rightarrow G\times X$ given by $(g,x)\mapsto (g,g^{-1}x)$. The former is an isomorphism (because it's the identity) and the latter is an isomorphism because it has an inverse $(h,y)\mapsto (h,hy)$ (i.e., $(g,x)\mapsto (g,g^{-1}x)\mapsto (g,gg^{-1}x)=(g,x)$ and the other way goes similarly).