# Action of algebraic group is smooth

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, algebraic-groups

Let $k$ be a field and $X$ be a $k$-variety (separated of finite type), let $G$ be a smooth algebraic group over $k$ acting on $X$
$$a \colon G \times_k X \longrightarrow X$$
I am needing a reference that this action morphism is smooth. There is a [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2481325/smooth-morphism-induced-by-the-action-of-group-schemes) here which gives a simple proof but I am writing a document and I need to cite it from a precise reference. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried Milne's book on algebraic groups? Or maybe even the Stacks Project?

Comment: @K02 thanks, I literally forgot Milne's book because I use Humphreys and Waterhouse instead.

Comment: The map $\alpha$ is the composition of the map $(g,x)\mapsto (g,g(x))$ with the second projection. The first map is an isomorphism (with inverse $(g,x)\mapsto (g,g^{-1}(x))$) so smoothness follows. It might be that there is no precise reference for this because it is easy to prove.